# ConnectionPool::PoolShuttingDownError thrown once in a while by application_controller rails using Mongodb replicaSet

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, replicaset, moped

I have a RoR application running on two different server. They run the same version of the app and are similar in configuration. I have a Mongodb replica set running on both the server with a third server as an arbitrary server.

Everything runs fine. The data is syncing perfectly. But after 2 weeks of running, one of the server started giving ConnectionPool::PoolShuttingDownError. I checked the log and I can see the error was raised application controller. I didn't change any code on any of the server.

The server raising the error is fine till it gets 6-7 simultaneous request. Or when you refresh the page 6-7 times together. It gives this error once and then again you refresh the page and its back to normal. This is weird and I can't understand why one server has this problem while the other one don't and that too sometime.

I am using Mongoid with Moped, Rails 4.1.0 and Ruby 2.1.5. I also checked available connections using db.serverStatus().connections which is around 51158 and ulimit of max process is 257185.

I searched a lot but I am still unsure of the cause of this problem. It will be great if someone can put some light on this issue. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/mongoid/moped/issues/346, with open PR https://github.com/mongoid/moped/pull/351

Comment: @PetrBela Thanks.. i ll have a look at it.

Comment: In our case, increasing the `pool_size` option fixed the issue. I think it's 10 by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you tell me how much will be good pool size? Is there a way to calculate pool_size?

Comment: Depends on what Ruby server you're using, with what configuration. For example if you're using Puma, you should set pool_size to the total number of threads Puma can scale to.